# Ephemeral vs. EBS vs. Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, cassandra, backup, storage

I am trying to determine what storage to use for Cassandra and Cassandra backups.  EBS is the most expensive of the lot so that one I may have pretty much eliminated.  ephemeral storage is cheaper compared to S3 if I am planning to commit to pay upfront for 3 years.  Not sure how it compares relative to S3 in terms of performance.  Anyone have experience for the two use cases (running a database and storage for backup)?

Answer (score 3):

With Cassandra its recommended to use ephemeral for you data and backups to S3. EBS is generally considered an anti-pattern and not recommended but the ssds can work.  Check out http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/planning/architecturePlanningEC2_c.html

Comment: Why not use ephemeral storage for backup as well?  It is cheaper than S3 and I am guessing faster from a recovery standpoint?

Comment: cheaper mostly, tend to have a lot of backups. You want to keep your data drives ~50% empty if using default compaction strategies so you don't want too many snapshots sitting around. Also with data going away with ephemeral you get a little more safety.

Comment: Do not use ephemeral storage for backups. The contents will be lost if the instance is stopped. Amazon S3 does not have any storage space limits, so you can keep your backups as long as desired. BTW, Netflix uses Cassandra on Amazon EC2, storing data on ephemeral volumes. Just search YouTube for a video at an AWS or C* conference.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that you store your database files on EBS, your cache files on ephemeral storage and your backups are saved to S3.

Ephemeral storage is purely for the purpose of temporary caching. It is deleted whenever the server reboots. If the box goes down you lose everything on it. DO NOT store important data on Ephemeral storage!

EBS is a SAN attached disk, you can stripe data across them to produce the performance you need. It is designed for storing working data on, and is safe from anything that could happen to the VM.

S3 is akin to a remote file share, it doesn't have the performance you need to install working data to, and can't (easily) be mounted, hence is ideal for backing up to. You can then have archiving and long term storage options set.

**Edited to be more Cassandra specific**

While Cassandra is designed to be fault tolerant, and accept the complete loss of cluster nodes. Unless you are designing it to be heavily distributed across multiple regions you still run the risk of losing all of your data up to the point of your last back up if you don't use EBS volumes. Since you are concerned about cost I am guessing that you aren't looking to be massively distributed, so it would be more cost effective to have all of your databases on EBS volumes that way if a region fails you won't lose data to ephemeral storage.

Comment: Are you sure about ephemeral storage being lost across reboots?  I read somewhere (probably on stackoverflow) that data survives over reboots but not if  you shut down the instance.  If my information is accurate, what is the downside of using ephemeral storage?

Comment: @JayDesai the problem is that it isn't guaranteed to survive, generally if you reboot ephemeral storage will stay, but if the host your machine is running on is approaching a maintenance schedule you would be transferred to another host and lose the storage. Also if there is an issue with the region / host you will lose the storage.

Comment: You generally get the safety from ephemeral drive shutdowns by spreading data across different regions and availability zones. EBS should generally be avoided unless you have strong reasons. In this C* has different recommendations than other databases. Its focus on high availability and great multi-dc replication makes the data durability in ephemerals less of a concern.

Comment: There is no practical reason to avoid EBS anymore - gp2 gives predicable iops, and EBS optimized instances give more than enough performance, Cassandra can easily max out CPUs without taxing gp2. The was reliability issues have been addressed, it's no longer a spof in a region.